# How to link navigateToURL to create a new record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it possible to navigate to the record page and have the create object modal popup? The code below links to the list of records of the object specified by 'a1V', but I want the create record page for that object to show up when redirecting.

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
  "url": "/a1V/o"
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a component on the page that fires a [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) event in a [modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) from the SLDS doc.

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "ObjectName"
});
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Actually, the form is poplated by default in a modal when you fire the Event...

anyways, if you need a custom component, you can use the modal and prepopulate it with whatever fields you need, and use a server side controller to create the record.

Comment: Man, I hate this [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) event. It doesn't allow me to redirect to whatever page I wanted after record creation, rather takes me to new record detail page. I've implemented complete custom component only because of this reason.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I did also same as you, please vote on the idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VnmQAE